# How to develop a calendar GUI in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, calendar

here's the code I currently have... My class barely introduced Tkinter and the book we're using doesn't help with understanding how to use the Calendar library. The labels Mon/Tu/Wed/Etc work, but the calendar isn't showing.

Images:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbMYM.jpg)
[problem cont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2naJ.jpg)

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
from calendar import *
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
#create labels
        for i in range(7):
            label = Label(self, text=days[i])
            label.grid(row = 0, column = i)

        weekday, numDays = monthrange(year, month)
        week = 1
        for i in range(1, numDays + 1):
            button = Button(self, text = str(i))
            button.grid(row = week, column = weekday)

            weekday+=1
            if weekday > 6:
                week +=1
                weekday = 0
```

Comment: This example gives: ***NameError: name 'year'*** and ***TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'method'***.  Read up on [Tutorial - 6.4.1. Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package). See a working [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/InsubstantialHorizontalSampler#main.py)

Answer (score 1):

First, you should consider creating, at the end, the mainloop:

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

It should work fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from calendar import *


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()

        year = int(raw_input('\nEnter Year eg. 2017\n'))
        month = int(raw_input('\nEnter month number.\n'))
        self.create_widgets(year, month)

    def create_widgets(self, year, month):

        days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
#create labels
        for i in range(7):
            label = Label(self, text=days[i])
            label.grid(row = 0, column = i)

        weekday, numDays = monthrange(year, month)
        week = 1
        for i in range(1, numDays + 1):
            button = Button(self, text = str(i))
            button.grid(row = week, column = weekday)

            weekday += 1
            if weekday > 6:
                week += 1
                weekday = 0


mainWindow = tk()
obj = Application(root)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

While calculating `monthrange()` the `year` and `month` variables were undefined. So what I did was I took the input for these variables from `__init__()` itself, so at the beginning of the program it would ask a month and year. After having that I simply passed it to `create_widget()` as parameter which were then used in `monthrange()`. Also added `mainloop`

Answer (score -3):

Python program to print calendar for given year

importing calendar library

```
import calendar 

def printcalendar(year): 

# printing calendar 
print(calendar.calendar(2020)) 


year = 2020
printcalendar(year)
```

Comment: How is this answering the question? The question is about creating a calendar with a GUI written in tkinter. Please read carefully the question before answering and have a look at [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise your answers won't be useful and you will get downvotes.